# jquery interdependent dropdown lists

Tags: jquery

I have 3 dropdown lists of same elements. Values selected in first list should not get displayed in second dropdown list. Values selected in second list should not get displayed in third dropdown list. How to do it using jquery?

Comment: $(".ACL").change(function(event){
   //alert($("#ACL1 option:selected").val()); 
   preferenceObject["acl1"]=$("#ACL1 option:selected").val();
   //alert("acl1 pushed");
   //alert($("#ACL2 option:selected").val());
   preferenceObject["acl2"]=$("#ACL2 option:selected").val();
   //alert("acl2 pushed");
   preferenceObject["acl3"]=$("#ACL3 option:selected").val();
  });

Comment: <div class="ACL">
     ACL :
 
     <select name="ACL1" id="ACL1">
     <% for(int i=0; i< ACLList.size(); i++)
     {
       if(ACLList.get(i)!=null){%>
          <option value="<%= ACLList.get(i) %>"><%= ACLList.get(i) %></option>
       <%}
     } %> 
     </select>

Comment: similarly i created acl2 acl3 in div acl. bt nw i dunno wt to do!! m fetchin acllist by request.getattribute

Answer (score 2):

Check out demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezKDB/

Jquery Plugin: https://github.com/WilliamHuey/mutually_exclusive_list_jquery

Usage:

```
$('select.classNameForEachList').onlyBeOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

***HTML***

```
<select class="sel-1">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


<select class="sel-2">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


<select class="sel-3">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

***jQuery***

```
var allSelects = $('select[class^=sel-]');
allSelects.on('change', function() {
  allSelects.find('options').show();
  allSelects.not(this).find('option[value="'+ this.value +'"]').hide();
});
```

***[The working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mr6wp/2/)***

Hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: what is this?--> $('select[class^=sel-]');

Comment: dis is wt i wanted... thank u so much :-) . ll try to use it in my code. Bt m using id for each dropdown list

Comment: @anil ok, you can use.. but using a common class is easier... its your choice. but don't forget to accept as answer

Comment: $('select[class^=sel-]'); m nt gettin dis line.

Comment: @anil it selected all `select` box whose `class` name start with `sel-`.

Comment: it is nt workin wen i pasted d code in eclipse.  html code i wrote in body and js code in head

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution:

```
<html>
<body>
<select id="first" data-child="#second">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
<option value="5">five</option>
<option value="6">six</option>
<option value="7">seven</option>
</select>

<select id="second" data-child="#third">
</select>

<select id="third">
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(init);

function mapItems(index, elem){
    var items = [];
    items.push({value:$(elem).val(), text:$(elem).text()});    
    return items;
}

function replaceItems(items, appendTo){
    appendTo.empty();
    for(var i in items){
        var item = items[i];
        if(item.value && item.text){
            appendTo.append("<option value='"+item.value+"'>"+item.text+"</option");
        }
    }
}

function selected(e){        
    var items = $(this).find("option:not(:selected)").map(mapItems);
    var child = $($(this).attr("data-child"));
    replaceItems(items, child);
    child.change();
}

function init(){
    var first = $("select#first");    
    var second = $("select#second");    
    var third = $("select#third");
    first.change(selected);
    second.change(selected);
    first.trigger('change');
}​
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not very pretty, but it works. See demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/goranobradovic/JLMJn/).

**UPDATE** I have cleaned code up. This is link to last version: http://jsfiddle.net/goranobradovic/JLMJn/2/

**UPDATE 2** I have put all html here, just copy it to empty html file and it works.

Comment: when i pasted d same code in eclipse.. it s showin nthn in 2nd n 3rd list

Comment: Paste to notepad first, jsfiddle sometimes puts some weird character at the end

Comment: dat is fine.. bt it is nt showin any value in 2nd and 3rd list. html code i wrote in body and js code in head

Comment: If you took this js code, you need to use data-child attributes in html, like in jsfiddle. First select has data-child="#idofsecondselect" and second select has data-child="#idofthirdselect"